# R dataframe: Convert list of 2 to simple numeric datatype

Tags: r, numeric

I wrote following function to replace NA's by 0.

(I need that because I upload the dataframe in a database in a numeric field that won't accept "NA")

```
REPLACE.NA.ZERO = function (x){
  X = 0
  ifelse(is.na(x)=="TRUE",X,x)
}

mydf["myvar"] = apply(mydf["myvar"], 2, REPLACE.NA.ZERO)
```

Problem is that my function changes the myvar datatype to:

```
> str(mydf)
$ myvar: num [1:18880, 1] 0 43 6 0 0 21 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr "value"
```

How to avoid this or how to get it back to simple numeric datatype please:

```
> str(mydf)
$ myvar: num 0 43 6 0 0 21 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Comment: Why does this change bothers you? The added attributes are no big deal.

Comment: @Pop: sqlSave function stumbles on it, it is a big problem for me.

Comment: Just a side note: you could replace `ifelse(is.na(x)=="TRUE",X,x)` with either `ifelse(is.na(x),X,x)` or more explicitly `ifelse(isTRUE(is.na(x)),X,x)` - same concept as using `is.na(x)` instead of `x == "NA"`.

Comment: @user3817704 can add the `dput(head(mydef))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use the `as.numeric` function that will suppress the attributes (`attr`) and convert your matrix `[1:18880, 1]` to a numeric array `[1:18880]`:

```
mydf$myvar <- as.numeric(mydf$myvar)
```

**EDIT**

A better solution is to replace your function `REPLACE.NA.ZERO` by the simple following command:

```
mydf[is.na(mydf)] <- 0
```

It is much simpler and, more importantly, `mydf` datatype does not change with this command!

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, improved my R skill :)